# References for the mathematical safe problem ?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request

An input to Mathematical Safe problem is represented by the 4-tuple $(L,K,S,X_0)$, where

- $L=[n]$ is the set of locks,
- $K=(k_1,\dots,k_l,\dots,k_n)$, where $k_l$ is the number of the states of the lock $l$ and each state set of lock $l$ is a set of congruence classes modulo $k_l$ ($\mathbb{Z}_{k_l}$),
- $S=(S_1,\dots,S_l,\dots,S_n),S_l\subseteq L,l\in S_l,\forall l$,
- an initial tuple of lock states $X_0=(x_1^0,x_2^0,\dots,x_n^0), x_l^0\in \mathbb{Z}_{k_l},\forall l$.

Let $x_l^j$ be the state of lock $l$ after turn $j$. Initially we are given a tuple of states $X_0$. After a single clockwise turn $j$ of the key in a lock $l$ all the locks $l'\in S_l$ pass from a state $x_{l'}^j$ to a state $(x_{l'}^j+1)\bmod k_{l'}$. The solution is the sequence of turns which opens the safe, i.e. brings it to the set of lock states $X=\{0,0,\dots,0\}$. The goal is to find a solution with minimum number of turns.

I know that this problem has been studied in some papers after 2002 year by one author, [Donets G.A](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22mathematical%20safe%22&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1,5). But it seems to me that it was studied before. Am I right in this respect and if so what references are there on this problem?

Comment: (1) I cannot understand the problem.  Why are you given many states instead of one state?  (2) You wrote “b_l = {0, 1, …, k_l − 1}”, but that should be “b_l ∈ {0, 1, …, k_l − 1}.”  (3) In the sentence after the itemized list, is it really “(b_j + 1) mod b_l” or a typo for “(b_j + 1) mod k_j”?

Comment: I agree. There are many problems in the formulation.

Comment: In the post there are two typos. $S_l$ should be a subset of $Z$ and instead of $b_l$ in $(b_j+1)\bmod b_l$ should be $k_j$. I've corrected that. Sorry for this. And Tsuyoshi you're right about $b_l\in\{0, 1,\dots, k_l − 1\}$.

Comment: I still fail to understand the problem and in particular why you are given many states instead of one state.

Comment: The "state" of the safe is multidimensional, where each "coordinate" is drawn from the modulo set over some $k$. Each lock influences a subset of the states. Think of it like the combination lock on a suitcase (in which N is often 3 or 4)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Indeed, we are given one state, from which we are required to open the safe with minimum number of turns. When I wrote about B as a set, I meant it as the set of all feasible states.

Comment: This seems like a special case of the general problem of linear programming with modular arithmetic. Maybe googling those keywords might help.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Maybe you meant by many states in "$b_l\in\{0,1,\dots,k_l−1\}$ is the set of states of the $l$-th lock". I've corrected this too as follows: "$b_l\in\{0,1,\dots,k_l−1\}$ is the state of the $l$-th lock".

Comment: It does not seem to me that in your formulation, you are given any state as a starting point.  I read your formulation as you are given some set B of states, whose meaning is unclear.  What is the input of your problem?  Please try to write it a little more rigorously.  For example, putting an equation inside braces like “{b=(b_1,…,b_N)}” is sloppy and I do not understand its meaning in the current context.  (Suresh: I understand that a state is a vector.)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I've described an input to this problem.

Comment: Thanks, now I can understand the problem.  (Nitpicking: 1. The capital N should be the small n.  2. You used braces {} to describe both a set and a tuple, but I do not think that it is a good writing style.  A tuple is usually written with parentheses ().)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Thanks for comment, I changed $N$ to $n$. Concerning tuples notation: I know about usage of () for tuples (this can be seen from the phrase "4-tuple $(L,K,S,X_0)$). I thought about this and came to conclusion that since all the expressions in braces are sets (i.e. in all cases symbols with different indices) it's justified to use {}. Even tuple $(L,K,S,X_0)$ can be seen as a set with this reasoning. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: In many cases {3,5} and {5,3} are the same thing.  (3,5) and (5,3) are different.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I've corrected notation for sets/tuples.